# How can I optimize this query that has a cartesian product and subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm looking to optimize this query which when running `explain analyze` on gives an execution time of `4168.39 ms`. Note that there are `2597504` records that match the first query named as `events`. I'm essentially looking to create a histogram which has 10 intervals between a min and max time.

I must admit I'm not the strongest at writing queries and it's something I'm looking to improve in. It was hard enough to even get a working query since it's quite complicated. I haven't been able to optimize it much more than the current state. Any help is much appreciated!

```
with events as (select detection_event_create_time from detection_event where detection_id='c10a18cb-fd80-4ffa-a844-25026e0a0000'),
stats as (select min(detection_event_create_time) as min, max(detection_event_create_time) as max from events)
select width_bucket(detection_event_create_time, min, max, 10) as bucket,
        int8range(min(detection_event_create_time), max(detection_event_create_time), '[]')
        as range, count(*) as freq
        from events, stats
        group by bucket order by bucket;
```

Here is the query plan which should also be useful

```
Sort  (cost=609366.41..609366.91 rows=200 width=44) (actual time=4159.556..4159.556 rows=11 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (width_bucket((events.detection_event_create_time)::double precision, (stats.min)::double precision, (stats.max)::double precision, 10))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   CTE events
     ->  Seq Scan on detection_event  (cost=0.00..432630.99 rows=2356310 width=8) (actual time=0.028..1953.462 rows=2597504 loops=1)
           Filter: (detection_id = 'c10a18cb-fd80-4ffa-a844-25026e0a0000'::text)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 5866850
   CTE stats
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=58907.75..58907.76 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=3026.711..3026.711 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  CTE Scan on events events_1  (cost=0.00..47126.20 rows=2356310 width=8) (actual time=0.031..2734.669 rows=2597504 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=117815.52..117820.02 rows=200 width=44) (actual time=4159.540..4159.545 rows=11 loops=1)
         Group Key: width_bucket((events.detection_event_create_time)::double precision, (stats.min)::double precision, (stats.max)::double precision, 10)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..94252.42 rows=2356310 width=12) (actual time=3026.729..3688.959 rows=2597504 loops=1)
               ->  CTE Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=3026.713..3026.714 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  CTE Scan on events  (cost=0.00..47126.20 rows=2356310 width=8) (actual time=0.010..275.809 rows=2597504 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.254 ms
 Execution Time: 4168.939 ms
```

Sample schema of `detection_event` table

```
           Column            |             Type              | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 user                        | text                          |           | not null |
 detection_event_id          | text                          |           | not null |
 detection_event_type        | detection_event_type          |           | not null |
 detection_event_create_time | bigint                        |           | not null |
```

Sample data from `detection_event` table

```
  user   |                 detection_event_id                  | detection_event_type | detection_event_create_time
---------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------
 user5   | sha256:sHmrskRgXxww03Vj9ZrhYIh+cCwlMol1VTabcABcAbc= | PRIVATE              |               1604022050726
 user4   | sha256:4JGmZyC+HiQYHwVwt9A27FuTXwJA1XFOv/abcABcAbc= | PRIVATE              |               1604022122612
 user3   | sha256:PflTYvP+SEIQNlrGWe2u0Kf9csZRGH6v4+abcABcAbc= | PRIVATE              |               1605300720564
 user8   | sha256:M6frdehhkBrthMBBNRv/RYkl1tJd6blvXVabcABcAbc= | PRIVATE              |               1605407979282
 user1   | sha256:mKvwF1yvOvGIVtLqmUm8CNtpSj5H7/vNV5abcABcAbc= | PRIVATE              |               1605408028382
```

Comment: does detection_event  table have an index on detection_id including detection_event_create_time  ?

Comment: @MitchWheat it does not (as of yet). I'm going to be adding that, however I'm wondering if my query itself could be improved. I figure the cartesian product `from events, stats` is costly since it adds two fields (from stats) to each record in events.

Comment: pls post example schema and some  data.

Comment: @MitchWheat added, should've done that sooner. This is a subset of the schema and data, other parts, including some of the fields provided are not used in the query. The only important field is  `detection_event_create_time`. The query can be run without specifying a `detection_id`, it'll just result in more records.